# Global / local scoping in Razor MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I've recently started delving into MVC Razor web programming, and I'm pretty much stuck with some basics.

I have this code:

```
@ { 
using WebMatrix.Data;

WebGrid grid;
if (!Request.QueryString["partID"].IsEmpty())
{
    var backQuery = Request.QueryString["partID"];
    var db = Database.Open("SQLServerConnectionString");
    var baseQuery = "SELECT * FROM Person.Person WHERE FirstName =@0";
    var selectedData = db.Query(baseQuery, backQuery);
    grid = new WebGrid(source: selectedData);
}

grid.GetHtml(); }
```

So the idea behind this is to have a user form that will get something from the DB and display it back to the user using WebForms WebGrid functionality.

However, I'm having the issue in the above code because the grid.GetHtml() generates an error of scoping issue. Is this some specific problem with Razor syntax scoping because this should work in normal C#, or it's something else that I'm missing.

Thanks.

Comment: if you have scope problem then place that code:grid.GetHtml(); outside of the @{ } because that block was used to write the c# code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment because I don't have reputation to do so yet.

A few things here:

1. Add some exception details.
2. We can't see what library you're using for the db.Query nor the version of WebGrid you're using.
3. If "partId" is in fact empty, you're calling a method on a null reference.
4. When using the MVC pattern, try to avoid doing logic like this in the view.  At least put it in the controller (or repository if you prefer that sort of thing) and give your results to the model.  Provide default data to the model.

Comment: You seem to be on point here. It's probably with returning the NULL reference and then "showing it" without any data in it. I'll try to add some default value to it.

Comment: DaveG, I solved the issue. You helped me realize that the value was returning empty and it caused an error. Because of that I had to reformat the whole concept and I ended up doing it inside the IF clause. You can check the current code here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/VVEDJJ